# Run R code for all files in a directory and output all files in a separate directory

Tags: r, csv, directory, package

Input csv files are input1 input2 input3....up to input50. Now there is R code which is to be run on each of these files and the respective csv outputs are output1, output2, output3,...up to output50. Is there exists some R functions or R package or R code which hen started take it file one by one and after applying some R opeartion, generates the respective output (one by one) in a septate folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
# set working directory to folder with input .csv files
setwd(input_dir)
# get a list of files
input_files <- list.files(input_dir, pattern = "[.]csv")

# loop for reading input and writing an output
for(i in 1:length(input_files)){
  df0 <- read.csv(input_files[i])
  df <-  ... do some operation on df0 ...
  write.csv(df, file = file.path(output_dir, paste0("output", i)))
}
```

**Edit:** for loop correction, thank's Chetan Arvind Patil.

Comment: .@AndriyT - I think for loop should traverse from `1` to `length(input_files)`, so it should be: `for(i in 1:length(input_files)){`?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil correctly said.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a function `ProcessCSV` to process one CSV file given it's name:

```
ProcessCSV=function(fileName) {
   df=read.csv(fileName)
   #your code to process data in data.frame
   write.csv(df, file=paste('output_',filename,collapse='',sep=''))
}
```

Then, you need to create a list of your files, either by filling in file names manually:

```
files=list(paste('input', 1:50, '.csv', sep=''))
```

or by listing all files in some directory:

```
files=list(list.files(path=".", recursive=T, pattern='.csv'))
```

After that, use `do.call` function to call the function in it's first argument for every entry in the list (second argument):

```
do.call(ProcessCSV, files)
```